# list menu element place them side-by-side

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

I am trying to get my unordered list elements to be sitting side-by-side next to each other on a navigation menu bar.

Problems:

1. <strike>I have set the display to be "inline" but that seems to not make any difference.</strike>
2. <strike>The nav bar (.nav in css) is not taking up the 100% of the width space, I have attempted to fix this by giving the width 100% but yet there are gaps either side of the nav bar.</strike>
3. Lastly, when the window is put into full screen the positioning of the nav bar (.nav) is changed due to the background image expanding, is there a way I can stop the background from expanding when window is made bigger so it won't have an impact on the positioning of the nav bar?

Following is my attempt, can anyone spot where I've gone wrong? Much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <h1 class="logo">LogoHere</h1>
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li>Action</li>
                <li>Who we are?</li>
                <li>Blog</li>
                <li>Services</li>
                <li>Get in touch</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.nav{
    background-color: #2EC0FE;
    opacity: 0.75;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 100%);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 600px;
}

.logo{
    font-family: times, Times New Roman, times-roman, georgia, serif;
    font-size: 54px;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: -5px;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.nav-menu 
{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Image problem 3:
This is when the window is not full screened and this is just the way I want my nav bar to be positioned
[image]

Following is when it is full screened and you can see the background image has expanded and now the nav bar position is much higher then how I want it to be in the first image.
[image]

Comment: try adding `display: inline` to `.nav-menu li` instead of `.nav-menu`.

Comment: @Harry that was perfect.. but now they are all appearing below the LogoHere (refer to the image). It would be nice to have it on the same line next to it

Comment: `h1` element is by default a `block` element. Hence you have to add `display: inline-block;` to `.logo`. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cV8ZL/). I have avoided the other nice-to-have effects in the example. If all your issues are solved, I will consolidate them into a single answer.

Comment: @Harry perfect! eaxctly what i wanted to achieve in terms of the first problem. one question, how to get some space in between each list elements? Padding or margin didn't do the trick

Comment: @Harry oh nvm, I've fixed it.. The margin was suppose to go in the nav li, i was putting it in just nav haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Item:**

1. Add `display: inline;` to `.nav-menu li` instead of `.nav-menu`.
2. `h1` (and so are other heading tags) is by default a `block` element. To display it in same line as the menu, add `display: inline-block;` to `logo`.

**Second Item:**

1. The `body` by default has margins. Hence to make the `nav` bar take the entire space, you have to add `body {margin: 0;}` to the CSS.

**Third Item:**

1. Add `position: absolute; bottom: 0px;` to the `.nav` class. This will put the bar at the bottom.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cV8ZL/3/) covering all three above items.

Comment: Thank you so much Harry, that fixed my first two problem. Fiddler wasn't very good in explaining the third problem so therefore I have added some images to my question to illustrate my problem. Please have a look. Any question, please let me know.

Comment: @Umz15: I get it now. Try adding `position: absolute; bottom: 0px;` to the `.nav` class. That should solve it. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cV8ZL/3/)

Comment: Man, thank you very much. You've solved all my issues. Been stuck on it for days. Really appreciate your time :]. Any tips or sites which would benefit me further?

Comment: Good to know mate. I am now updating the answer with this item also. The best site that I would recommend is Google, then [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and StackOverflow (of-course). [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com) has a lot of info, but make your mind up on whether to use it or not after checking [this](http://www.w3fools.com). Matter of fact, I still do ;)